# prolog expanding predicate to iterate for multiple results, combining / resolving result sets

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate "lookupOptions" which returns one by one some lists (Menus).

I'm trying to get it to satisfy the case of multiple inputs. I can return a single set of options as follows, by reading the head of the "list_places" list.

```
find_options(Restaurant,Town,Menu) :- lookupOptions(Restaurant,H,Menu), list_places(Town,[H|T])
```

But, I'm not able to get it to iterate.

I have tried a lot of things, these were my best efforts so far.

a) standard enough iteration, but it wont resolve ...

```
doStuff(X,[],_).
doStuff(Restaurant,[H|T],_):-  lookupOptions(Resturant,H,_), doStuff(Restaurant,T,_).
find_options(Restaurant,Town,Menu) :- doStuff(Restaurant,[H|T],Menu), list_places(Town,[H|T]).
```

b) expanding the goal predicate ...

```
find_options(_,Town,[H|T],_)
find_options(Restaurant,Town,Menu) :- find_options(Restaurant,Town,[],Menu).
find_options(Restaurant,Town,X,Menu) :- list_places(Town,X).
find_options(Restaurant,Town,[H|T],Menu) :- lookupOptions(Restaurant,[H],Menu), find_options(Restaurant,Town,T,Menu).
```

Would either of these work ? if the pattern was written correctly. Or if there was an appropriate cut put in place?

Any help most appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no clear on *what* you want iterate. Prolog uses backtracking to examine all alternatives, then you should start backtracking if you are after some *alternative*, or use the [all solutions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.29%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29) family.

Now I think you want simply declare there could be more `find_options(Restaurant,Town,Menu)`. Then try replacing the head match `[H|T]` with this:

```
find_options(Restaurant,Town,Menu) :-
   lookupOptions(Restaurant,H,Menu),
   list_places(Town, Places),
   member(H, Places).
```

BTW `T` is a singleton in your original rule. This could be a hint for the need of generalize it.

Comment: Adding member(H, Places) to the RHS of the predicate is exactly what I needed. It allows resolution of all the solutions/options to be looked up. You Sir are my hero today. Thank you.